# What is more appropriate here - since or from?

Tags: prepositions

Which one is correct here?

1. I am not working in this problem from yesterday onwards.
2. I am not working in this problem since yesterday onwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not working in this problem from yesterday onwards.
>
> I am not working in this problem since yesterday onwards.

Neither are correct as they stand - you have a mix of tenses

**I am** is only used in present and future tenses

**working** is an indicative progressive verb that can be used for past (*I was working / I have been working*, present *I am working* and future *I will be working*) tenses

**in this problem** We would normally expect *on this problem* or *in this area*

**since yesterday** puts this in the past

So, a correct alternative would be:

> I have not been working on this problem since yesterday.

or

> I have not worked on this problem since yesterday.

The second one would be my personal choice.

Note that the **onwards** is redundant - it doesn't really add anything and is probably a tautology.

Hope that helps

Comment: Three of us posting at once - that's not bad service :)

Answer (score 0):

As you have it written, with the current tense of "I am not working in" (which does not sound natural), I would probably choose "from".  But, if I were to change the tense to something a little more natural, I would state:

> I have not been working on this problem since yesterday onward.

In this case, the second feels better, though from would work as well.  Personally though, I would use the simpler:

> I have not worked on the problem since yesterday.

as the idea of "onward" is implied.

Answer (score 0):

Neither is correct, in my opinion. There are a few issues. First, it should be ***on*** this problem, not ***in*** this problem. Also, the first clause has to be changed to *present perfect continous*, which you can read about here: http://www.englishgrammarsecrets.com/presentperfectcontinuous/menu.php

A correct sentence might be this:

> I have not been working on this problem since yesterday onward.

You can omit the 's' at the end of *onward*.